# Change to enum not being saved to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I have created an action on my controller, with the aim of it changing the order status when someone clicks a 'Place Order' button. This is the code I have, which fires no errors, and also when placing the breakpoints in, I can see Order.Status does is set correctly. However EF does not seem to be saving the change of the enum value to the database. If I change strings/int's etc it works fine, but not enums. What am I doing wrong?

```
   public ActionResult PlaceOrder(int id = 0)
    {
        Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
        if (order == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }


        order.Status = ServerApplication.Helpers.Enums.OrderStatus.Receive;

        db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return (RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = order.OrderId }));

    }
```

This is how Order is defined:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public ServerApplication.Helpers.Enums.OrderStatus Status { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And finally, the enum:

```
    public enum OrderStatus { Pending, Receive, Complete }
```

**Edit**

I've done some further investigation, and my earlier assumption that it was just when editing them that it didn't change was incorrect. Upon exploring the database it would appear none of the enum's have columns in the database. My views were just returning the first value, making me think they were correct when they weren't. I'm using code first EF5, why using my model above is there not a column for Status?

Comment: have you tried casting the enum example `db.Entry(order.State = (int)EntityState.Modified`

Comment: What version of EF are you using? Bare in mind that enum support was only introduced from [V5 onwards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh859576.aspx).

Comment: I'm confused. My target framework is .NET 4.5 but if I go to References->system.data.entity then the version is v4.0.30319. The website you like to, suggests VS2012 with 4.5 will default to V5.

Comment: Ah, in the PMC it says I am running EntityFramework 5.0.0

Comment: Are you using code first?

Comment: Yes. Also worth adding that when creating a new Order, it saves the enum fine without issue - it's just editing where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I was declaring the enum inside a class:

```
namespace ServerApplication.Helpers
{
    public static class Enums
    {
        public enum OrderStatus { Pending, Receive, Complete }
    }
}
```

Removing the class and simply having the following fixed the problem:

```
namespace ServerApplication.Helpers
{
    public enum OrderStatus { Pending, Receive, Complete }
}
```